# Questions about hexachord on p.31 of the Study of Counterpoint

Tags: theory, modes, counterpoint

p. 31 of [*The Study of Counterpoint*](http://www.opus28.co.uk/Fux_Gradus.pdf) by Johann Joseph Fux (translated by Alfred Mann) says:

[image: page 31]

I don't understand what this page is telling us. I understand what a hexachord is. However, why note is `G` not a correct note in D Dorian mode? D Dorian mode is: `D`, `E`, `F`, `G`, `A`, `B`, `C`, and `G` is the 4th note in Dorian mode, right? So why is this note wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what your reference is. Is "p.31" referring to a page number? Of what book? Maybe the book  "The study of counterpoint" by whom?

Comment: In order that this question receives some answers, you need to be a lot clearer with its wording. Thanks.

Comment: Hi sorry for the confusion, it's the page 31 from the book 'the study of counterpoint' by Johann Joseph Fux  (Author),‎ Alfred Mann (Translator), many thanks

Comment: @Tim and nath, does this edit meet your approval?

Answer (score 6):

The problem in that particular part of Fux's *The Study of Counterpoint* is not that G doesn't belong to the mode at all, but that the student is putting the G *below* D in the first measure. The first measure of a species counterpoint exercise must make the modality completely clear, but a G on the bottom would cause the exercise to sound initially as if it was in G Mixolydian instead of D Dorian. This is a problem in this context because the exercise will clearly end in D, and species counterpoint exercises don't modulate.

The upshot of this is that, although the initial consonance can be a P5th when a student is writing an upper counterpoint to a cantus firmus, it is *not* an option when writing a lower counterpoint. That's why the teacher says it wasn't the student's fault, he just hadn't told him about the rule yet.